# How to check that the options in dropdown are displayed twice in Selenium Webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am stuck in one logic, where I have to verify if the options in dropdown are displaying twice. I searched in google for the solution, but didnt find any.

I have this code to get all the options from the dropdown. But not really sure how should I check if the options are displayed twice.

```java
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id='unmappedTech']))).selectByVisibleText(VisibleText);
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id='unmappedTech']))).getOptions();
```

In my application, options are displaying twice in dropdown. Here is the source code of dropdown:

```html
<table><tbody><tr>
 <td>
  <select name="unmappedTech" id="unmappedTech" multiple="multiple" size="10" style="width: 160px;">
   <option class=" firepath-matching-node" value="142">Cloud Service Assurance</option>
   <option value="123">Cloud Service Assurance Zenoss for Data Center and Cloud</option>
   <option value="6">CUSTOMER COLLABORATION</option>
   <option value="12">DESKTOP VIRTUALIZATION</option>
   <option value="13">FACILITIES</option>
   <option value="7">INSTANT MESSAGING</option>
   <option value="8">MOBILE COLLABORATION</option>
   <option value="141">Network Address Translation</option>
   <option value="15">NETWORKING</option>
   <option value="3">SECURITY</option>
   <option value="16">STORAGE</option>
   <option value="81">TestTechnology_Dont_Delete</option>
   <option value="10">UNIFIED COMMUNICATIONS</option>
   <option value="20">VCH VIDEO</option>
   <option value="17">VIRTUALIZATION  And  CONSOLIDATION</option>
   <option value="21">VtechnologyVtechnologyVtechnologyVtechnology</option>
   <option value="2">WIRELESS</option>
   <option class=" firepath-matching-node" value="142">Cloud Service Assurance</option>
   <option value="123">Cloud Service Assurance Zenoss for Data Center and Cloud</option>
   <option value="6">CUSTOMER COLLABORATION</option>
   <option value="12">DESKTOP VIRTUALIZATION</option>
   <option value="13">FACILITIES</option>
   <option value="7">INSTANT MESSAGING</option>
   <option value="8">MOBILE COLLABORATION</option>
   <option value="141">Network Address Translation</option>
   <option value="15">NETWORKING</option>
   <option value="3">SECURITY</option>
   <option value="16">STORAGE</option>
   <option value="81">TestTechnology_Dont_Delete</option>
   <option value="10">UNIFIED COMMUNICATIONS</option>
   <option value="20">VCH VIDEO</option>
   <option value="17">VIRTUALIZATION  And  CONSOLIDATION</option>
   <option value="21">VtechnologyVtechnologyVtechnologyVtechnology</option>
   <option value="2">WIRELESS</option>                  
  </select>
 </td>
```

Comment: Is your app supposed to have duplicate options in the dropdown? I'm not sure if you want to report it as a pass or a fail if it does.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Java person, so forgive me, but you are essentially just wanting to `loop` through all the `options` from that `Select`, keep a record of them, and ensure that one each `loop` iteration, that `option` doesn't already exist, so pseudo-code:

```
Select selectElement = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id='unmappedTech'])));
ArrayList<string> options = new ArrayList<string>();
for (WebElement element in selectElement.getOptions()) {
    if (options.contains(element.getText())) {
        // do something that lets the test fail because the option is listed twice
    }
    options.add(element.getText());
}
```

This isn't a Selenium problem as such, it's just comparing a `list` to see if something is already `contained` within that `list`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the java code. Essentially checking whether duplicate is found by rechecking a set.

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElement(
        By.xpath("//*[@id='unmappedTech']")).findElements(
        By.tagName("option"));
HashSet<String> optionNames = new HashSet<>();
for (WebElement option : options) {
    if (optionNames.contains(option.getText()))
        System.out.println("Duplicate found");
    else
        optionNames.add(option.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//Select[@id='unmappedTech']")));
        List<WebElement> list = s.getOptions();
        Set<String> listNames = new HashSet<String>(list.size());
        for (WebElement element : list) {
           //Set will not allow to add duplicate value
            if(listNames.add(element.getText())==false){
                System.out.println("Duplicate value is: "+element.getText());
            }
        }
```